# Restrict jQuery confirmation dialog when link is disabled

Tags: jquery, html, anchor

I have a link:

```
<a id="my_link" data-method="post" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to do this?" class="btn btn-success disabled" href="#">My Link</a>
```

And the following jQuery (in CoffeeScript):

```
$('#my_link').click (e) ->
  if $(this).hasClass('disabled')
    e.preventDefault()
  else
    # Do other stuff
```

Unfortunately, if it has the class of `disabled`, the confirmation dialog is still appearing. I assumed `e.preventDefault()` would do the trick, but alas it has not.

How might I prevent this?

Comment: `preventDefault` prevents the default action of an event, it doesn't prevent execution of handlers.

Comment: depending in which order and how the handler for dialog is appended a `e.stopPropagation()` would do it. but this requires that this handler is called before the one for the dialog is triggered.

Comment: Thanks @martincarlin87, that does work. I wish preventDefault did prevent execution of handlers as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @martincarlin87 suggested. The solution was to `return false` after preventing default. I wish this wasn't needed, but the response comment on my question seems to answer it.

> `preventDefault` prevents the default action of an event, it doesn't
>   prevent execution of handlers. – undefined

**Update**

Bringing up one of the comments. @mcpDESIGNS stated that `e.stopPropagation()` prevents the upcoming event handlers. By doing `return false` it does both `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: You could of also done `e.stopPropagation()` (which would prevent the upcoming even handlers). `return false` in a jQuery event simply does both `preventDefault && stopProgagation()` for you.